# why do i get a blank screen switching between msm sites after upgrade?

Tags: multi-site-manager, blank-screen

Installed EE 2.8.x today with newest msm.

Now when I switch sites or edit sites, I get  blank page.

URL is something like:
http://subdomain.domain.com/admin.php?/cp/sites/manage_sites?S=1b89ab94f128fbe5ee247f319cea09ca

Note: 1/3 msm sites is a subdomain of domain1. File paths seem okay. On server domain 2 is a sub-folder of domain 1.

I can log into separate CPs using subdomain or domain. Actual sites work fine to public users.

Answer (score 1):

There are a heap of errors with version 2.8 mostly to do with javascript.

https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20165

Also P&T add-ons seem to have been particularly affected, users reporting issues with Playa, Matrix etc.

There's no ETA on a fix right now just that one is coming with the 2.8.1 release. So I'm playing safe and sticking with 2.7.3